# Using "transform: scale()" as zoom function, adding positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use `transform: scale()` as zoom function. But I also would need to change the position of the zoom with moving the mouse cursor. Would be best if the zoom area is as big as the image.

Some code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').hover(function() {
    $("img").addClass('zoom');

  }, function() {
    $("img").removeClass('zoom');
  });
});
```

```css
.image_area {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50h;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.zoom {
  transition: 0.1s transform linear;
  transform: scale(5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image_area">
  <img id="content" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/51/78/75/51787599df00f30466df5a0ba8da9463.jpg">
</div>
```

So in general, what is missing there:
Changing the zoom position with moving the cursor!

Would be very thankful for help! :)

Comment: with moving the cursor... moving it where?

Comment: Hey! It should look like the solution from Monzoor Tamal, but without the use of "background-image". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<div class="zoom" onmousemove="imageZoom(event)" style="background-image: url(//res.cloudinary.com/active-bridge/image/upload/slide1.jpg)">
  <img src="//res.cloudinary.com/active-bridge/image/upload/slide1.jpg" />
</div>
```

css

```
div.zoom {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}
div.zoom img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
div.zoom img {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
function imageZoom(e){
  var zoomer = e.currentTarget;
  e.offsetX ? offsetX = e.offsetX : offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX
  e.offsetY ? offsetY = e.offsetY : offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX
  x = offsetX/zoomer.offsetWidth*100
  y = offsetY/zoomer.offsetHeight*100
  zoomer.style.backgroundPosition = x + '% ' + y + '%';
}
```

UPDATE:
Here your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/3vx461dw/15/)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do it without the background-image? I load the image with jQuery and it's hard to get it twice.

Comment: show me how you load the image with jq. Then i can come up with a solution

Comment: That's it in general: https://jsfiddle.net/xsujcyf5/ – and I need the zoom for the lightbox view.